# How to update first response date field(custom object) on case object

Tags: trigger, case, chatter-feed, emailmessage, recordtriggeredflow

Hi am new to salesforce and I have a task

I have to capture the first email date sent from case - meaning the date from chatter feed and populate it to a field.
Should I use a flow or trigger for this task ? Any help is appreciated. [image]

Comment: yeap you can use a flow trigger for this case and populate the field with the date when the flow runs.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a record triggered flow based on the EmailMessage object. You can have it run only if the message is outbound and related to a case record (via Related Object Id starts with 500, [see here](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-object-key-prefix-list/)).

Then you can have it update the related case with the response date.

Comment: out bound meaning = email message( is incoming = false ) is that the logic ur looking for